# passing data through 3 classes taking selected values from 1 and inputing into textbox's of another

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay I'm taking information based off of selected text in a combobox passing it to a textbox on another form.

I have a class called variables

```
public class variables
{
    public string Design { get; set; }
    public string Classnum { get; set; }
}
```

that is receiving info from user selections in combo boxes 
This is in another class called home

```
private void cbfanclass_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var.Design = cbdesigntype.Text.ToString();
}
```

When I use a break point i see that var.Design is holding the correct data.

where my problem starts is when i send it over to my 3rd class

```
public partial class DesignPar : Form
{
    public variables var = new variables();

    public DesignPar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DesignPar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = var.Design;
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I'll enter data in textbox1 to activate the event but nothing appears in textbox 2 and using break it shows that var.design//textbox 2 is just ""  not null but ""
so my question is obviously i'm passing the data wrong somewhere

Comment: Let me see where you instantiate the `DesignPar` form.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are creating a new instance of variables  class

you have to create a private property in DesignPar()  like this

```
private string design {get; set;}
```

and add a overloaded constructor taking a parameter

and pass parameter to it that constructor from class home

like this

> DesignPar(cbdesigntype.Text.ToString())

and in your overloaded constructor assign the value

```
DesignPar(string design)
{
  this.design = design;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, and bare withme, but where exactly should i be putting the DesignPar(cbdesigntype.Text.ToString())

Comment: have a look at this link, it will help you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ef14e60-28fb-43d5-9c10-14463444d2e3/to-pass-values-between-two-forms-using-c

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that some kind of button click launches your DesignPar form...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DesignPar form = new DesignPar())
        {
            form.var = var;
            form.ShowDialog();

            var = form.var;
        }
    }
```

Now in DesignPar...

```
public partial class DesignPar : Form
{
    public variables var = null;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (var == null)
            var = new variables();
        textBox2.Text = var.Design;
    }
}
```